# connect to web site by ip address

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm new in C++ programming and I am trying to make a simple client socket program to connect a website by its ip but when I run the program it encounter an error and display "Failed to connect".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "winsock2.h"

void main() {

// Initialize Winsock.
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData );
if ( iResult != NO_ERROR )
    printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n");

// Create a socket.
SOCKET m_socket;
m_socket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );

if ( m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET ) {
    printf( "Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Connect to a server.
sockaddr_in clientService;

clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "173.194.123.14" );
clientService.sin_port = htons( 80 );

if ( connect( m_socket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
    printf( "Failed to connect.\n" );
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

}
```

I wanna to know this is a right way to connect a website or not? if not, how can I connect to website by its ip? anybody can help me?

Comment: Facing any problem? If so, please state it.

Comment: Code not quite formatted correctly at the top. SO wont let me edit it as its less than 6 characters.

Comment: In the code that handles the `connect` failure can you call ` WSAGetLastError` and see what the error code is?

Comment: It connects fine for me using vs2008. Can you ping 173.194.123.14?

Comment: I called 'WSAGetLastError' and I add the following command: printf("First step done"). I ran the program and it displayed these results: """ First step done process returned 0 <0x0> execution time : 0.456 s press any key to continue. """
what is the meaning of result? do I achieve to my goal and I could connect to website?

Comment: I use vs2010. yes I can ping "173.194.123.14".  after I changed my code I received other results, shown in the following. could I connect to the website?

Comment: if ( connect( m_socket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
    printf( "Failed to connect.\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}
printf("First step done");

}